# Ruby regexp returning "" vs nil

Tags: ruby, regex

What is the reason behind different results between the following regexp statements:

```
"abbcccddddeeee"[/z*/] # => ""
```

And these that return `nil`:

```
"some matching content"[/missing/] # => nil
"start end"[/\Aend/] # => nil
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regular expression `/z*/` matches 0 or more `z` characters, so it also matches an empty string at the beginning of your string. Consider this:

```
"abbcccddddeeee" =~ /z*/
# => 0
```

Thus `String#[]` returns the matched empty string.

In your second example the expressions `/missing/` and `/\Aend/` don't match anything so `nil` is returned.

Answer (score 9):

What's happening is that `/z*/` will return **zero or more** occurrences of `z`.

If you use `/z+/`, which returns one or more, you'll see it returns `nil` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`*` wild-card stands for 0 or more matches so even if your z is not present it will show a empty string match. on the other hand you can use `+` for 1 or more and `?` for zero or more matches.